# How to put all print result in a function into a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, io-redirection

I have a function in Python:

```
def f():
    ...
    a lot of code
    ...
    print "hello"
    ...
    a lot of code
    ...
```

I want to call this function, however, the print result will be put into a variable instead print on the screen directly. How can I do this with Python?
ps:
please don't just return, sometimes I don't know where the print statement is.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, isn't this a perfectly reasonable question?

Comment: I assume that it's because your question is unclear. It is usually best to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can reproduce your issue. Also, some people will downvote just because leaving no explanation. I find this not helpful at all.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `print` is writing to `sys.stdout`, you can temporarily replace that with something like a `StringIO` object.

```
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StringIO()
f()
x = sys.stdout.getvalue()
sys.stdout = stdout
```

Or, if you have a reference to the file handle that `print` is using, you can use that instead of `sys.stdout`.

If there are multiple uses of `print` from inside `f`, and you only want to capture *some* of them (say, only from a function `g` called from inside `f`), I'm afraid you are out of luck. The amount of introspection you would need to do would make it possible would allow you to simply re-implement the function to accumulate the desired output in a variable instead of using `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a decorator like below

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO
s = StringIO()


def catch_stdout(user_method):
    sys.stdout = s
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        user_method(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        print 'printing result of all prints in one go'
        s.seek(0, 0)
        print s.read()
    return decorated


@catch_stdout
def test():
    print 'hello '
    print 'world '


test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also define your own context manager if you find you need to do this a lot so you can capture the output for a block of statements, eg:

```
import contextlib
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_stdout():
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    yield sys.stdout, old_stdout
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Then use as follows:

```
def something():
    print 'this is something'

# All prints that go to stdout inside this block either called
# directly or indirectly will be put into a StringIO object instead
# unless the original stdout is used directly...
with capture_print() as (res, stdout):
    print 'hello',
    print >> stdout, "I'm the original stdout!" 
    something()

print res.getvalue() + 'blah' # normal print to stdout outside with block
```

Gives you:

```
I'm the original stdout
hello this is something
blah
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def f():
    #code
    variable = 'hello\n'
    #code
    variable += 'hello2\n'
    #code
    ...

    print(variable)
```

or

```
def f():
    #code
    variable = 'hello\n'
    #code
    variable += 'hello2\n'
    #code
    ...

    return(variable)
```

and then

```
print(f())
```

Comment: I don't know where the print statement is, because I invoke other function in this function.